# How to establish your bundle dependencies?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle

So I'm on my way to want to release my very first symfony bundle and I want to add the `composer.json` file that states the information about the bundles it depends on. I know I have some dependencies on `doctrine/common` and the `doctrine orm bundle` but I am not sure what is the minimal and/or the maximal version of these bundle my code will support. Is there a way to test this? (the same question would go for the php version. It works in php 5.3 but I didn't test it on all versions)

Answer (score 0):

You can check php requirements of any vendor in its composer.json file.
Check composer.json for doctrine/common that you want to use.
example:

https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/composer.json

this vendor will work with php 5.5

if Your bundle will support lower version of php then you have to look for previous version of this vendor

Comment: Thanks! I guess this somewhat helps to establish the minimal php version. But aren't there other releases of the doctrine common bundle so that if you install version 2.3 say you will have different requirements for php. I am asking how to write the composer for a vendor :-S

Comment: "I am asking how to write the composer for a vendor"
Do you want to create list of dependencies for your bundle? If yes then create composer.json file in your bundle root dir.
Exactly the same like it is i.e. DoctrineBundle:
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle

Comment: Yep. I  am asking how to establish for the bundle that I wrote what is the minimal and maximal version of `doctrine/common` I need for my bundle. I really thought this was clear from the question